# Blender doesn't run my script unless blender crashes?

Tags: python, scripting

I have the most unusual and frustrating issue at the moment. I've got a script, but I just can't get it to run. I've tried live edit, not live edit, using the run script button with and without the register check box. I've even tried starting a new blend file and importing everything as a proper add-on. None of them work.

BUT, if for what ever reason, blender crashes, (which it is doing quite a lot at the moment... (I'm running the macOS Sierra beta which I probably shouldn't have done), then the script updates, and runs perfectly. It's just so impossible to use right now.

Comment: Can you post the script?

Comment: Might need the macbook.blend file too.  Slight note, when context is passed to a class method eg `draw(self, context):`  use that ( `obj = context.object`) rather than `obj = bpy.context.object`.  Without aforementioned file, my guess is that it's a lost reference.

Comment: @batFINGER Are you sure about the .blend file? I'm intending on selling this and I'd rather not redistribute the files. As for the other part, I don't quite understand, which parts are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a bug in your script.  Run blender from the command line, and it will tell you what the error is there.

Update: I found that node in your code in the beginning of it, you have a several lines that say `s_slots[0].material.node_tree.nodes['S_R_MS'].inputs[0].default_value = 0.0`
I suspect that is where the S_R_MS node is.

Comment: Well we're getting somewhere now, it gives me this error: "Error, couldn't find thumbnail for Theatrical lighting"  No idea what this could be, do you know?

Comment: Ok, I found it, it's an icon from the Pro Lighting Studio add-on. I was lucky enough to be a beta tester on that so I'm now thinking that something may have slipped through...

Comment: Ok, now I know somethings up. When I change the enum in the UI, it gives me an error saying the node 'S_R_MS' could not be found. That would be because I have since removed that node, but I have also removed that from the code and replaced it with something else, it doesn't seem to be updating...

Comment: Can you upload your .blend? (If you want to sell this, you might not want to upload it, but then I can't help you.)

Comment: On the account that you don't redistribute it!

Comment: I won't, but someone else might.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that it was really simple. The two lines at the bottom of the script were commented out:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Uncommenting them did the trick.